# Best retry policy for Refit ApiException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, polly, refit

I´m using both **Refit** and **Polly** to call to restful API´s and I´m wondering what the retry (if any) policy for Refits ApiException should be?

```
public static PolicyWrap MyRetryPolicy()
{
        // Try few times with little more time between... maybe the 
        // connection issue gets resolved
        var wireServerNetworkIssue = Policy.Handle<WebException>() 
                                    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] {
                                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)});
        var policyList = new List<Policy>();

        // But if there is something wrong with the api
        // I should do what (if general)?
        var api = Policy.Handle<ApiException>()
                  .RetryAsync(1, onRetry: async (exception, i) =>
                  {
                       await Task.Run(() =>
                       {
                           // What would be normal to do here?
                           // Try again or do some circuit braking?
                       });
                  });

        policyList.Add(wireServerNetworkIssue);
        policyList.Add(api);

        return Policy.Wrap(policyList.ToArray());
}
```

And then I use it like this

```
try
{
    myApi = RestService.For<MyApi>("api base url");
    var policyWrapper = Policies.Policies.MyRetryPolicyWrapper();
    var response  = await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => myApi.SendReceiptAsync(receipt));
}
catch (ApiException apiEx)
{
  //Do something if the retry policy did´t fix it.
}
catch (WebException webEx)
{
  //Do something if the retry policy did´t fix it.
}
```

**The Question**

What would be a **normal retry policy for ApiExceptions**? Would you just circuit brake or under what general circumstances would you do something to recover?

The answer is probably "it depends on what your service returns" but I just have to ask.

Comment: You should not need the `await Task.Run(() => { } );` in the `onRetry` delegate of your original question (unless you intentionally want to run the `onRetry` action potentially on a background thread).  Simply using `await` within the delegate will give the delegate a `Task`-based return type.  Also, if you want the onretry action to run asynchronously, use Polly's `.RetryAsync(...)` overloads taking the `onRetryAsync` parameter, not `onRetry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ApiException`s returned contain meaningful [`HttpStatusCode StatusCode`](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/blob/32ad31e0eb6362590c462219ea3b47b554ab3b5e/Refit/RestService.cs#L74) properties, you could certainly choose which of those StatusCodes merit a retry; the [Polly readme](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md#step-1b-optionally-specify-return-results-you-want-to-handle) suggests:

```
int[] httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying = {408, 500, 502, 503, 504};
```

For `ApiException`s specific to the API called, only knowledge of what those API-specific errors represent, can guide whether to retry them.

If you choose to circuit-break on too many exceptions of some kind, that should be achieved by wrapping a circuit-breaker into your [`PolicyWrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap), rather than within the `onRetry` delegate of the retry policy.  Polly discusses 'Why circuit-break?' [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Transient-fault-handling%3A-why-Retry-and-Circuit-Breaker%3F#circuit-breaker), and links to a number of other circuit-breaker blog posts at the foot of the [readme circuit-breaker section](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#circuit-breaker).